# Does VS Code, Python, and .py files need to be on the same hard drive?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Or can they be on separate hard drives along with certain files on the local disk?

I ask because I have been running into issues where imports cannot be found or errors in the terminal stating no such file or directory can be found

Thank you in advance!

Comment: They don't need to be on the same hard drive.

Comment: If you're having issues with imports not being found, ask about imports not being found. Please read [ask] and about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: select the correct Python interpreter / virtual environment

Comment: set the path python correctly in edit variable and settings, and set a virtual environment correctly, typically, $ python --version.
$ Python 2.7.10.
$ pip -h.
$ python get-pip.py.
$ pip install virtualenv.
$ virtualenv [name of your new virtual environment]
$ cd [name of your new virtual environment]
$ source bin/activate.